# Is the Tax Treaty for J1 Research Scholar is for 2 Tax years or for 2 years starting from the Date of my J1 starts?

Tags: taxes, j-visa, tax-treaties

[image]I have come to US from India on J1 VISA (Category: Research Scholar) on 2nd April 2022 and my program started on 4 the April. Based on the tax treaty between India & US (article 21 or 22, In some of my documents its say Article 21 and in form 8233 it says Article 22, so am not sure) I am not liable to pay any taxes for the first two years. I have some questions regarding this two year rule. Is it two calendar years (i.e from 4th April 2022 to 31st December 2023) or 2 years starting from my program start date (i.e from 4th April 2022 to 3rd April 2024)? Which one is this? can someone please clarify? I searched a lot but could not find a proper answer. But in my treaty memo (8233) it says that "The treaty exemption is available only for compensation paid during a period of two years beginning on that date" (attached screenshot) which I guess should be 4 th April right? Can you please help me?]